# How to prompt for specific variable options and use variable from user input?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to expand my knowledge of PowerShell......

I am trying to write a script that aids in software installs. We install non-licensed software often for users remotely and use invoke command to copy and install the software currently, but I would like to write a script that already has the directories of all the software's we install as variables. When I run the script, it would list all the software as a menu selection and wait for an input on which software to install. Then based on the input, install the software remotely in a more automated manner.

```
$ComputerName = Read-Host "Enter Computer Name"

Function Get-ProjectType {
    $type=Read-Host "
    1 - App1
    2 - App2
    3 - App3
    4 - App4
    5 - App5
    Please choose Project Type"
    Switch ($type){
        1 {$projectType="App1"}
        2 {$projectType="App2"}
        3 {$projectType="App3"}
        4 {$projectType="App4"}
        5 {$projectType="App5"}
    }
    return $projectType
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock { & "C:\Software\{$projectType}\install.bat" }
```

Comment: [Get-Help about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.3). To use local variables in remote script blocks you can use the `$unsing:` scope modifier.